# MSSQL driver suddenly stopped working in Go

Tags: sql-server, go, module

After installing Go 1.17 and reinstalling all of the modules I use, I returned to a program I use for testing database calls. Running the program I originally compiled returns nothing. Building the program errors out.

I am using the `"github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"` module to connect to a local SQL Server database.  I have executed a `go get ...` for the module. Nothing returns from the command. No install messages. No `module up-to-date` message. Nothing.

Nor is the module showing in `go list ...`

So I perform an update `go get -u`.  This time it shows the `"golang.org/x/crypto"` module is loaded. Still no joy.

I am experienced with Assembler and C++ but I am relatively new to GOlang. I would appreciate suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue.  In particular, I want to learn how to fix issues like this in the future. Thank you for your time in advance

Comment: *"Building the program errors out."* -- What is the error message?

Comment: Have you tried running [`go mod tidy`](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-tidy)?